# Refinement of a covering of a space for a continuous surjection

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $p:X\to Y$ be a continuous surjection. For any covering $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ can we always find a refinement of the (not necessary open) covering $\{ p(U)\vert U\in \mathcal{U}\}$ of $Y$?

It is obvious that this has a negative answer when $Y$ is the indiscrete space (with the additional condition that there is $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $p(U)\neq Y$) and an affirmative answer when $Y$ is the discrete. Can we improve the conditions of the space(s) so that we can always get an affirmative answer?

Comment: how about compactness/normal spaces?

Comment: @A.Ekbote I'm afraid they won't help a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. Any cover is a refinement of itself, so the answer is trivially positive. On the other hand, if by 'refinement' you mean 'open refinement', then the answer is no: Any space is the one-to-one image of a discrete space, and any space maps one-to-one onto an indiscrete space.

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, I meant open refinement. Can you explain your answer in details, please?

Answer (score 0):

Given any space $Y$, we can take its underlying set and equip it with the discrete topology. Call the result $X$, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be the continuous bijection induced by the identity function. We can now equip $X$ with the covering $\mathcal{U}=\{\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$. The covering $f(\mathcal{U})=\{f(U)\mid U\in\mathcal{U}\}$ of $Y$ has no open refinement unless $Y$ itself is discrete.

Thus for a nondiscrete space $Y$ there will always be a continuous surjection $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and a covering $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ for which $f(\mathcal{U})$ has no open refinement.

On the other hand, given a space $X$, we can equip its underlying set with the indiscrete topology to yield a space $Y$ and a continuous bijection $f:X\rightarrow Y$. As long as $X$ has an open covering $\mathcal{U}$ which does not contain the whole space $X$ as a member, we have a covering for which $f(\mathcal{U})$ has no open refinement. There are $T_0$ spaces which do not satisfy this assumption, but what we can reasonably say is the following.

For any $T_1$ space $X$ with a least two points, there is a continuous surjection $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and a covering $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ for which $f(\mathcal{U})$ has no open refinement.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, but it does not answer to my question. It only gives some cases when such a covering does not exist.

Comment: Emo, the first part answers the question for all $Y$, and the second for all $X$ which are $T_1$ and have at least two points.

Comment: As I can understand, you are giving some conditions to the spaces when the question have negative answers. I am asking for some conditions of the spaces when the question will have affirmative answers.

Comment: Well, what conditions would you suggest that weren't met by the counterexamples in my answer?